# Create jks for tomcat using .key ,.ca and .cert file

Tags: tomcat, ssl-certificate, openssl, keystore, keytool

I have three file sample.cert, sample.CA,sample.key provided by Verisign. I need to create keystore for tomcat. As I searched I cannot use .key file directly to create keystore.

The command I used is below :

```
 pkcs12 -export -in sample.cert -inkey sample.key  -CAfile sample.crt -out sample.p12
```

(I changed sample.CA to sample.crt.)

I use openssl to create sample.p12 file. Then I import sample.p12 to sample.jsk by using keytool.

```
    keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore sample.p12 -destkeystore sample.jks -srcstoretype pkcs12
```

When I verify the certificate it shows `Intermediate certificate chaining issue`.

Any idea?

Comment: I couldn't figure this out so I just installed the [APR native library](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/apr.html) which adds support for openssl PEM/KEY files. It was easier in the end.